# Functions $h$ such that $h(x*x') = f(x) * g(x').$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, definition, magma

> **Definition 0.** Call a [magma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29) $X$ *surjective* iff the distinguished binary operation of $X$ induces a surjective function $X \times X \rightarrow X$.

Now for the main idea:

> **Definition 1.** Let:
>
> 1. $X,Y$ denote magmas, with $X$ surjective.
> 2. $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ denote functions, not necessarily homomorphisms.
>
> Then there is at most one function $h : X \rightarrow Y$ that satisfies the following equation for all $x,x' \in X$. $$h(x*x') = f(x) * g(x')$$
>
> If such a function exists, let us say that "$(f,g)$ *has a homotope*," and let us call it "**the** homotope of $(f,g).$"

This is my own terminology; it is inspired by the existing terminology "[homotopy of magmas](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Homotopy_of_magmas)".

> **Main Question.** I'm interested in sufficient conditions under which the homotope of $(f,g)$:
>
> 1. exists, and/or
> 2. not only exists, but also, happens to be a homomorphism.

The remainder of the question is discussion.

**Proposition 0.** Let $X$ and $Y$ denote any magmas, with $X$ surjective. Let $h : X \rightarrow Y$ denote a homomorphism. Then $(h,h)$ has a homotope, namely $h.$

The converse doesn't hold though:

**Example.** Let $X$ denote a set, and $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denote its powerset. Define a binary operation $\rightarrow$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ by writing $A \rightarrow B = A^c \cup B$. Organize $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as a magma, with binary operation $\rightarrow$. Then $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is surjective. Now given $A \subseteq X$, the function $(A \cap -) : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ that takes $B \subseteq X$ to $A \cap B \subseteq X$ is not, in general, a magma homomorphism. Nonetheless, the ordered pair of functions $(A \cap -, A \cap -)$ has a homotope, namely the function $(A \rightarrow -) : \mathcal{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ that takes $B \subseteq X$ to $A \rightarrow B \subseteq X$. Furthermore, the function $(A \rightarrow -)$ is always a magma homomorphism, for all $A \subseteq X$. Therefore, the converse to the above proposition is false.

Moving right along, the following theorem shows that if $X$ and $Y$ have identity elements, and if they're preserved by $f$ and $g$, then the concept "homotope" gives us nothing new beyond the concept "homomorphism."

**Proposition 1.** Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are magmas-with-identity. Then $X$ is surjective. Furthermore, if $f$ and $g$ are identity-preserving functions $X \rightarrow Y$ such that $(f,g)$ has a homotope, then $f$ equals $g,$ which equals the homotope of $(f,g)$, and they're all homomorphisms.

> **Secondary Question.** Where can I get more information?

Comment: Of course the questions are too general to be answered.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I am interested in partial solutions though. For example, is there a somewhat general principle that explains why $(A \cap -,A \cap -)$ happens to have a homotope? Is there a somewhat general principle that explains why its homotope happens to be a homomorphism? These are questions that interest me.